# jQuery/javascript to find/get values of form elements inside fieldset using ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, fieldset

How can we get values of form elements inside fieldset?

```
<fieldset id='myFieldset'>
  <label for='Resp'>Responsibilities</label><input id='input' type='text' size='55'>
  <button type='button' class='btn-sm' style='width:50px;margin:2px' id='addItem'>Add</button>
  <button type='button' class='btn-sm' style='width:50px;margin:2px' id='clear'>Clear</button>
  <button type='button' class='btn-sm' style='width:50px;margin:2px' id='edit'>Edit</button>
  <ul id='output' style='display:none'></ul>
  <br class='clear' /> 
  <textarea disabled name='Resp' id='Resp' cols='75' rows='5' required></textarea>
</fieldset>
```

I have some more fields similar to this in a page. So I need to get values from input form and also from specific fieldset. How can I do it in jQuery?

Comment: Use `$('#myFieldset #input').val()`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: You can use jquery selector to select input from specific fieldset id or direct select the input id like:
like: $('#input').val()

Comment: Theres nothing to do with fieldset. You can access values using jquerys val()

Comment: I have many such fieldset with different IDs in a page. I want to use javascript function to detect on which fieldset click event has occurred and get the input val().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/f3xwzap9/

```js
var data = {};

$('#addItem').click(function(){
  $('fieldset#myFieldset > input, textarea').each(function(){
    data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
  });

 console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id='myFieldset'>
  <label for='Resp'>Responsibilities</label><input id='input' type='text' size='55'>
  <button type='button' class='btn-sm' style='width:50px;margin:2px' id='addItem'>Add</button>
  <button type='button' class='btn-sm' style='width:50px;margin:2px' id='clear'>Clear</button>
  <button type='button' class='btn-sm' style='width:50px;margin:2px' id='edit'>Edit</button>
  <ul id='output' style='display:none'></ul>
  <br class='clear' /> 
  <textarea name='Resp' id='Resp' cols='75' rows='5' required></textarea>
</fieldset>
```

I have attached an event in **Add** button.
I'm **looping** through all the **input** & **textarea** inside the **fieldset** & collecting the data.

Data is in JSON format **id as key** and **value is value**.

Since I'm looping through all the **input** & **textarea**, it will help you to collect all the **child** (**input** & **textarea**) data, rather than collecting the data specifically.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have many such fieldset with different IDs. I want to use javascript function to detect on which fieldset click event has occurred and get the input val(). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using id attributes:

```
<input type="text" id="txtData" name="txtData" />
```

**JQuery:**
      $("#myFieldset #txtData").val();

If you are using class attributes.

```
<input type="text" class="txtEmail" />
```

**Jquery**
$("#myFieldset .txtEmail").val();

You are able to get all ids value from fieldset as below:

**Html**

```
<fieldset id='myFieldset'>
      <input type="text" id="txtData" name="txtData" />
      <input type="text" class="txtEmail" />
      <input type="button" class="btntest" />
  </fieldset>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".btntest").click(function () {
            $("#myFieldset input[type != button]").each(function(key,value){
                alert($(this).val());
            });
        });
```

So this thing will give you all inputs not then type = button value.

Comment: I have many such fieldset with different IDs. I want to use javascript function to detect on which fieldset click event has occurred and get the input val(). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var inputVal = $('#myFieldset #input').val();
var textAreaVal = $('#myFieldset #Resp').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#myFieldset').find('input').val()